# Rewrite IL to inject try-finally around method call

Tags: c#, .net, il, mono.cecil, fody

I want to inject sql logging into a few methods. Basically I want to transform

```
    public static object IDbCommandTest_ExecuteScalar(IDbCommand command)
    {
        // .. do stuff
        command.CommandText = "SELECT ...";
        var obj = command.ExecuteScalar();
        Console.WriteLine("SQL returned " + obj);
        // do other stuff
        return obj;
    }
```

into

```
    public static object IDbCommandTest_ExecuteScalar_Transformed(IDbCommand command)
    {
        // .. do stuff
        command.CommandText = "SELECT ...";
        object obj;
        using (SqlLogger.Enter(command, "IDbCommand", "ExecuteScalar"))
        {
            obj = command.ExecuteScalar();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("SQL returned " + obj);
        // do other stuff
        return obj;
    }
```

I got the easy cases working, the issue I am currently facing is that the stack must be empty when entering a `.try`.

My primitive assumption was that the `IDbCommand` itself was loaded directly before the call to `ExecuteScalar`, so I search for callvirt and then use `Instruction.Previous` as the start of the `.try`.

But if the return value of `ExecuteScalar` is used afterwards, the compiler generates the following IL:

```
    IL_004d: ldarg.0
    IL_004e: ldloc.1
    IL_004f: callvirt instance object [System.Data]System.Data.IDbCommand::ExecuteScalar()
    IL_0054: call string Class_which_uses_obj::DoStuff(object)
```

With my primitivy algorithm, this is transformed into

```
    IL_0050: ldarg.0
    .try
    {
        IL_0051: ldloc.1
        IL_0052: dup
        IL_0053: ldstr "IDbCommand"
        IL_0058: ldstr "get_FileName"
        IL_005d: call class [mscorlib]System.IDisposable SqlLogger::Enter(class [System.Data]System.Data.IDbCommand, string, string)
        IL_0062: stloc.3
        IL_0063: callvirt instance object [System.Data]System.Data.IDbCommand::ExecuteScalar()
        IL_0068: stloc.s 4
        IL_006a: leave.s IL_0077
    } // end .try
    finally
    {
        IL_006c: nop
        IL_006d: ldloc.3
        IL_006e: brfalse.s IL_0076

        IL_0070: ldloc.3
        IL_0071: callvirt instance void [mscorlib]System.IDisposable::Dispose()

        IL_0076: endfinally
    } // end handler

    IL_0077: nop
    IL_0078: ldloc.s 4
    IL_007a: call string        IL_0050: ldarg.0
    .try
    {
        IL_0051: ldloc.1
        IL_0052: dup
        IL_0053: ldstr "IDbCommand"
        IL_0058: ldstr "ExecuteScalar"
        IL_005d: call class [mscorlib]System.IDisposable Nemetschek.Allready.SqlLogger::Enter(class [System.Data]System.Data.IDbCommand, string, string)
        IL_0062: stloc.3
        IL_0063: callvirt instance object [System.Data]System.Data.IDbCommand::ExecuteScalar()
        IL_0068: stloc.s 4
        IL_006a: leave.s IL_0077
    } // end .try
    finally
    {
        IL_006c: nop
        IL_006d: ldloc.3
        IL_006e: brfalse.s IL_0076

        IL_0070: ldloc.3
        IL_0071: callvirt instance void [mscorlib]System.IDisposable::Dispose()

        IL_0076: endfinally
    } // end handler

    IL_0077: nop
    IL_0078: ldloc.s 4
    IL_007a: call string Nemetschek.Allready.Logistics.DbTools.CDbTools::GetSafeStringEmpty(object)(object)
```

Then PEVERIFY complains that I enter a .try with a non-empty stack.

Is there an easy way to inject the try-finally over just ExecuteScalar or do I need to do a complete flow analysis over the whole method, calculating the stack depth at any point and then loading/restoring the values before/after the try/finally?

**EDIT:**

I have been able to get it working by scanning up/down until I find two points where the stack-depth is 0. In my limited tests, this seems to work, but I would still be interested in a 'clean' implementation instead of blindly scanning the IL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would rewrite a call to `ExecuteScalar` into a call to a helper method:

```
static object ExecuteScalarWrapper(SqlCommand command, string logString) {
        using (SqlLogger.Enter(command, logString))
        {
            return command.ExecuteScalar();
        }
}
```

`ExecuteScalarWrapper` would be a static helper method that you can write in C# and reference.

Then, you do not need to inject any try-blocks. You just need to replace the pattern

```
ld... command
call ExecuteScalar
```

with

```
ld... command
ld... logString
call ExecuteScalarWrapper
```

which should be easier because the stack layout and modifications are locally defined and do not require any complicated reasoning.

Now the JIT does all the heavy lifting for you.